# A proof for boundedness of this ODE's solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \binom{x}{y} = A\binom{x}{y} + \binom{0}{x g(t)}$$

- $A$ is a constant;
- $g(t)$ is a bounded function, and all its derivatives are bounded;
- Solutions of $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \binom{x}{y} = A\binom{x}{y}$ are bounded $\forall t$;

Is there a simple/effective way (without solving it) to prove that the solutions remain bounded as $t\to+\infty$?

Comment: The matter is that your claim is false. Take say $A=0$ and $g=1$.